# Nothing works to remove UIViewController from screen

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, modalviewcontroller, ios5

I have a modal view with a button and on click I add a fullscreen view controller. In ios 4.3 sdk it was dismissing when I asked to (and with push/pop controller methods and with present/dismiss modalViews) In new ios 5 sdk it fails to exit, parentViewController of my viewController is nil and I'm stucked.
Any suggestions?

Adding code:

```
 myTypeController* vc = [[myTypeController alloc] initWithSomeData:myData];
 vc.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES
//This way  
//[self.parentViewController presentModalViewController:vc animated:NO];
//Or that
 [self.parentViewController.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
 [vc release];
```

And usual ways to remove it

```
 [self.parentViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

or 
     [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];

Answer (score 3, accepted):

iOS 5 requires that you use presentingViewController:

```
if ([currentView parentViewController] != nil)
{
    // iOS 4
    self.isDismissingView = YES;
    [[currentView parentViewController] dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:animated];
}
else if ([currentView presentingViewController] != nil)
{
    // iOS5
    self.isDismissingView = YES;
    [[currentView presentingViewController] dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:animated];
}
```

More info here: http://omegadelta.net/2011/11/04/oh-my-god-they-killed-parentviewcontroller/

Answer (score 1):

Use following code to close the modal view

```
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Comment: No, I need to close it from itself, not from parent viewController. Question already has been answered.